# Thread repeating the same message though it should have exited the loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, unix, mutex

I'm doing a SudokuChecker (if it is correct), that has 18 threads, one for each column and for each row. So, to check each column/row I order it with qsort, and then check that each position has the number it should. When it doesn't it stores an error message and exits the function (or so it should..).

This is how I create and delete the threads:

```
vector <thread*> threads;

for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
{
    cout << i << endl;
    thread* rowThread = new thread (&SudokuChecker::checkRow, this, i);
    thread* columnThread = new thread (&SudokuChecker::checkColumn, this, i);
    threads.push_back (rowThread);
    threads.push_back (columnThread);
}

for (thread* t : threads) t->join ();
for (thread* t : threads) delete t;
```

And this is how my function checks each column/row (slight change for each one):

```
bool SudokuChecker::checkRow (int row)
{
    if ((row < 0) || (row > 8))
    {
        cout << "Error in row parameter" << endl;
        return true;
    }

    int checkingArray [9];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) checkingArray [i] = mSudoku [row][i];

    qsort (checkingArray, 9, sizeof (int), compare);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        if (checkingArray [i] != i + 1)
        {
            std::stringstream error;
            error << "File ";
            error << mFileName;
            error << ": Error in row - ";
            cout << "entered row" << row << endl;
            error << row;
            error << '\n';

            while(!mMutex.try_lock());
            mErrorLog.push_back(error.str());
            mMutex.unlock();

            return true;
        }
    }   

    return false;
}
```

So, when I print the errorLog vector the output is the following:

```
File Grid01.sdk: Error in column - 1
File Grid01.sdk: Error in column - 1
File Grid01.sdk: Error in row - 1
File Grid01.sdk: Error in column - 1
File Grid01.sdk: Error in row - 1
File Grid01.sdk: Error in column - 0
File Grid01.sdk: Error in column - 1
File Grid01.sdk: Error in row - 1
File Grid01.sdk: Error in column - 0
File Grid01.sdk: Error in row - 2
File Grid01.sdk: Error in column - 1
File Grid01.sdk: Error in row - 1
File Grid01.sdk: Error in column - 0
File Grid01.sdk: Error in row - 2
File Grid01.sdk: Error in row - 0
File Grid01.sdk: Error in column - 1
File Grid01.sdk: Error in row - 1
File Grid01.sdk: Error in column - 0
File Grid01.sdk: Error in row - 2
File Grid01.sdk: Error in row - 0
```

The log is about 180 when at maximum it should be 18. My first guess was that if stored it every number error but that would mean 9 errors x 18 columns/rows, which is 162; but there are 171 errors.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The overhead of starting, stopping, and synchronizing all these tiny threads swamps any imaginable gain. Just call the functions one at a time.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed it, but it's for university, so there's nothing I can do but do it

Comment: Okay. Don't learn too many bad habits. `<g>`

Comment: You can save yourself all the trouble of copying the array and sorting it by just using an int as a bitmask, each time setting the appropriate bit when encountered and then comparing the result to 0x1ff (this should also give you a single error per thread, though you could also achieve that with the use of a break statement). If you must sort, I'm not sure qsort is worth it for such a small array, maybe something simpler is better here, not sure. Also, I think you're missing an index in the loop (shouldn't it be i < 9 ?)

Comment: How many times does "entered row N" appear in your output?